# Gitlab CI fails to schedule builds for new commits

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, gitlab-ci

I have several projects on Gitlab integrated with Gitlab CI. However, the only time when build is scheduled in gitlab_ci for them is when I press `Test settings` in the gitlab_ci integration ingitlab project's services.

In all other cases, that is, when a commit is made to any of branches of the Gitlab project, no build is sheduled in gitlab_ci. What is aggravating is that `Test settings` only shedules a build of default branch (that is, `master`).

What can I do to diagnose and fix the situation? What logs should I look into? What settings to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the initial push, GitLab creates the following symbolic link

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/[namespace]/[project].git/hooks ->   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
```

But when the project is created manually, the symbolic link would not be created automatically.

tl;dr 
[Git-Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) are used to trigger events such as new commit or new tag

Comment: When the repository was added manually in the GitLab Filesystem.